# Custom balance accounts testrpc?

Tags: contract-debugging, truffle, testrpc

I am setting up unit tests with for my contracts using truffle. I am using also testrpc, but having accounts with `2.123...... *10^37` Wei is not very helpful to visualise and debug things.

I am trying to setup custom testRPC account balances using `$ testrpc --account="<privatekey>,balance"` as seen [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc). However, what I get back is one account with again "infinite ether".

I have also tried to do :

```
var TestRPC = require("ethereumjs-testrpc");
var accountConfig = [
  {balance: 20000000},
  {balance: 20000000}
];
web3.setProvider(TestRPC.provider({accounts: accountConfig}));
```

as seen [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) and [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/7) , however truffle complains it cannot find the module `"ethereumjs-testrpc"`.

In short the question then is : how to set up custom account balances for testRPC?

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc), you can explicity specify a new account address and balance using the following syntax:

> `--account`: Specify `--account=`... (no 's') any number of times passing arbitrary private keys and their associated balances to generate
>   initial addresses:
>
> `$ testrpc --account="<privatekey>,balance" [--account="<privatekey>,balance"]`
>
> Note that private keys are 64
>   characters long, and must be input as a 0x-prefixed hex string.
>   Balance can either be input as an integer or 0x-prefixed hex value
>   specifying the amount of wei in that account.

I'd suggest running `testrpc` without the `--account` option to get the randomly generated list of addresses, making a note of them, and then using them in conjunction with whatever balances you want them to have (by passing them to `--account`).

Comment: I don't understand the formatting of the documentation command

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for pointing it out. There was an extra `>` in there which made it look odd. I've removed it. The important part is `--account="<privatekey>,balance"`, which can be repeated multiple times, one for each account you want to add.

Comment: Sweet thanks, why do they surround `private key` in `<>` though?

Comment: @DanielKobe.  Just because, really.  It's a convention, although there may be some original historical reason.  This is similar to keyboard commands being surrounded by brackets, e.g. [command]

Comment: Thanks, @JohnAllen. I'd missed this follow-up question. :-)