# Add accounts to truffle test environment at run time

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing, truffle-contract

I would like to add the keys and unlock some additional addresses at runtime for my truffle tests.

Why?  I have the need to create address from a seed generated elsewhere in my test so the private keys don't exist until part of the test has run.

I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
EthereumBip44 = require('ethereum-bip44')
# create the hd wallet
wallet = EthereumBip44.fromPrivateSeed(tree.keccak);
confirms = [
  wallet.getAddress(0)
  wallet.getAddress(1)
  wallet.getAddress(2)
  wallet.getAddress(3)
  wallet.getAddress(4)
]
```

And then later I'll need to send some transactions from these accounts.  How can I add them so that I can call one of my truffle functions from them?

```
contractCompiledWithTruffle.myFunction('dosomething', from: confirms[1])
```

Comment: An easy solution is to add an extra account at the beginning that will not be used https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/custom-balance-accounts-testrpc, and when you need the new accounts just make a transfer from the extra account to them.

Comment: The issue is that I don’t know the address I want until after the test has run because the private key is based on a result in my test. I can transfer funds, but how do I unlock to do new transactions later in my test.

Comment: With ganache you can specify the extra account to be unlocked, then sending a transfer to the new addresses will just work.

Comment: Do you have a ref to the documentation on this?  If so you will be my hero.

Comment: Take a look at [`ganache-cli`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) documentation. It has parameter `--account` to create an account with a predefined private key and the parameter `--unlock` to unlock an account.